# Compiling a CUDA file, C file, and Cuda header file

Tags: c++, c, cuda, makefile

I have a CUDA kernel I want to launch from a C file. I put the Kernel in a .cu file, and made a wrapper function that calls the kernel. I then made a header file that simply declared the wrapper function. In my C file, I included the header file and called the wrapper function.

What would my makefile look like if I wanted to compile these files to objects and then link them?

Comment: Use `nvcc -c` to compile all CUDA-files and `gcc -c` to compile C-files. After that simply link them by gcc. I recommend you to use `cmake` in projects with more than 2-3 files.

Comment: @Eddy_Em: "simply linking" with gcc requires adding all of the CUDA runtime and driver component libraries to the linking statements, which can be tricky. Linking with nvcc eliminates all that complexity and is usually preferred.

Answer (score 1):

nvcc uses file extension to determine language and compilation trajectory automatically. So you would actually only need a single compilation statement, which could be as simple as:

```
application:     foo.cu bar.c
                 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) -XComplier=$(CFLAGS) -Xlinker=$(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

[DISCLAIMER: written in browser, doesn't contain tabs, never tested, exact form will depend on the flavour of make is used, use at own risk]

Define whatever CUDA specific options you need in `CUDAFLAGS`. I think it will work without enclosing the `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables in quotes, but you might need to experiment a bit with that.